# Flutter Google Maps - Unknown Map ID Error

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter, google-maps-ios-utils

Every time this code is run:

```
await mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: currentPos)));
```

I get the following error:

```
flutter: Unknown map ID 0
flutter:
#0      GoogleMapsFlutterIOS._channel
google_maps_flutter_ios.dart:58
#1      GoogleMapsFlutterIOS.updateTileOverlays
google_maps_flutter_ios.dart:357
#2      GoogleMapController._updateTileOverlays
controller.dart:147
#3      _GoogleMapState._updateTileOverlays
google_map.dart:397
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Flutter version 3.3.0, google_maps_flutter 2.2.8.

Tried to update google maps to show current location, but keep getting unknown map error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the minimal code that can reproduce this issue.